# Alternative to Rhino for expression parsing in Java

Tags: rhino

In my  java program I use  rhino expression evaluator to parse an expression from a table into keys and values which is matched against a given java object . The performance of this evaluator is not that good and on an average takes about 50ms per evaluation. Is these a better / faster version of rhino or any other js interpretor that I can use.

Using compiled js interpretors like spiderMnkey as the whole code is Java.

Comment: FYI, similar issue regarding [instantiating native objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558405/instantiating-rhinoscript-native-objects-from-java-scala).

Answer (score 0):

Google's [v8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) engine is relatively speedy (and comes with some trimin's/utilities when pulled with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)), but without knowing a little more about your expressions and comparisons, it's hard to say if you'll get a significant speed boost by using another JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: Thanks. So here  would be sample of what I do . The following is the exression :  filedA == "X" && fieldB == "Y" && fieldC.indexOf("XYZ") != -1 . The interpreter is java.scripts.ScriptManager (). On that these field values are set as using the setBindings() method. then i use the interpreter.eval() method  to see if the given java object matches this expression.  Let me know if I can provide any more info.

Comment: 50ms seems like a long time for an `eval`, but I don't see anything that would indicate your expression is the issue. v8 is probably a good bet.

Comment: You would have to create the JNI wrapper for V8 first. Do such wrappers already exist?